Separating hyperplane for linear transformed convex polyhedron
Suppose I have a set $X=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n:Ax\leq b\}$ and the convex polyhedron $P=\text{conv}(X)$, a matrix $C\in\mathbb{Z}^{p\times n}$. Then I linearly transform the set $X$ using $C$, and obtain $Y=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^p:y=Cx, x\in X\}$ and its convex hull $Q=\text{conv}(Y)$. Suppose I have a point $\bar p\not\in P$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists a separating hyperplane $(\pi,\pi_0)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $\pi^T\bar p>\pi_0$ and $\pi^T p\leq \pi_0$ for all $p\in P$. My questions are,

Is it true that $\bar q:= C\bar p\not\in Q$?
If 1. is true, there exists a hyperplane separating $\bar q$ from Q. Does this separating hyperplane have any relations to the hyperplane defined by $(\pi,\pi_0)$?

It can be assumed that $p<n$ if that matters.


is false: take $C=0$.


@daw Ah, I see - I was so focussed on my use-case, that I simply did not consider the case with $C=0$. My bad. Is that the only case where it is not true? I think I can prove that $Q={ y\in\mathbb{R}^p: y=Cx, x\in P }$. Would that not prove that if $C\neq 0$, then if $p\not\in P$ implies $Cp\not \in Q$?
